# Adding bracket border to asp Gridview cell with different rowspan values (vertically merged cells)

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, border

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a Datalist that contains a gridview. This gridview has merged cells in specific columns. for these merged cells, i would like to display a left bracket created via css or similar. however when i run my code via css, the height of the bracket is the same for all merged cells. can you help me add this left bracket into merged cells, height of which will be the height of the merged cell minus couple pxs?

so if a merged cell has 7 rows in it, the bracket image should be higher than a merged cell that has 2 rows in it...

if you can solve this for left, please also detail how the right bracket will be added (for future work). thanks in advance!

ps: solution doesnt have to be in css.

Comment: Datalist? Gridview? This sure doesn't sound like asp-classic.

Comment: You also need to show us what you have done to warrant the help, really. Please read the help.

Comment: I would have shown what I meant, but the site doesn't let me attach images as I don't have enough points... I couldn't solve the issue, so I switched to a gridview and added image bracket image in itemtemplate. Thanks for reading anyways.